# What are the location based alarm applications available for Android?

Tags: alarm, geolocation

I want to know what apps can sound an alarm depending on my location.

Obviously it would be better if the battery consumption is low.

I'd be happy if the application is free but wouldn't mind paying if it's working properly with not much battery consumption. Also please post (if you can) only applications that you've used.

UPDATE: Sorry guys, I should have been more clear. The alarm I am looking for is something where I can set an alarm when I am in the bus/train and make it sound the alarm and wake me up before my stop.

Comment: reQall is what I have installed per friend recommending, but haven't really used it yet.

Comment: You're asking for a list of apps. This isn't the kind of question we like here. We prefer questions that ask how to solve a problem, not those that ask for shopping recommendations for your already defined solution. Please review the [FAQ].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama). A laymans version of Tasker. It can do so much more but should suffice with minimal battery impact as it uses cell sites to identify rather than gps.

Comment: This looks very promising! Thanx! Let's see :)

Answer (score 4):

A [quick search on the Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=location+alarm&so=1&c=apps) found a number of these. Here are a few that seem to fit your description.

- [Bus Stop Alarm](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.JamesBecwar.GPSAlarm)
- [Bus Snooze - GPS Alarm](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.Finko.BusSnooze)
- [Location Reminder Alarm](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cg.android.proximityalarm)
- [GPS Alarm+](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jiran.GPSAlarm2)
- [GPS Alarm](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.myandroid.mga)

Comment: FYI, These apps are all rated pretty poorly (the highest was  3.3 or so).

Answer (score 2):

Remember The Milk can do this: although it is a todo list utility, and a very good one, you can also set tasks to be triggered by geolocation (at the railway station? remember to text the parking fee) and these will set off the alarm of your choice.

Comment: Thanx! :) Please see my updated question. This looks overkill for my needs. Sorry! I should have been more clear!

Comment: In that case, you could, I think, program Tasker to do it. Not sure if you have to record the location first, though.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, but many of my friends will tell you (and so will a lot of people on this site!) that [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result) is what you're looking for, and it's well worth the price. It not only can make certain alarms active per location, but it can do any number of tasks, depending on if you're in a certain spot, if you have wi-fi access, if your battery is low, and so on. Here's the full description:

> Automate everything from settings to photos, SMS to speech. ADC2 prize
>   winner. Total Automation, from settings to SMS. ADC2 finalist!
>
> - Triggers: App, Time, Day, Location, Hard/Soft State, Event,
>     Shortcut, Widget, Timer
> - Actions: 175+ built-in, any Locale-compatible setting plugin
> - Tasks: loops, variables, conditions

Comment: Thanx! :) Please see my updated question. This looks overkill for my needs. Sorry! I should have been more clear!

Comment: it may do more than you ask for, but it could do what you're asking too (though it may not be worth the price for just the one function). for example, you could set an alarm to go off when you were within range of the location you wished to get off the train at, and tasker would only sound the alarm when in range of that location.

Comment: haha but i can definitely see how it would be overkill ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose an app I just published; it's [Are We There Yet?](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geoffreybuttercrumbs.arewethereyet), it has a fancy new Holo based UI, it allows you to save alarms for quick access and it is free.

Answer (score -1):

Check this [Milwus Location Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milwus.location_alarm) app.

Works nicely, it's exactly what you're looking for.